# Wordpress deletes my content while editing

Tags: wordpress, text-editor, html-editor

I've got problem with WP. I'm editing page with form, I wrote content in "HTML editor" but when I switch to "Basic editor" some tags disappear (some spans and textarea too)!

What's the problem???

Comment: Disable all plugins and swap to Twenty Twelve, does it still happens? Anyway, avoid switching editors, WP sucks for that...

Comment: In my experience , This is usually provoked by some JS error . If you can not easily identify it - your best chance in progressing to debug is follow brasofilo advice .